# Why MySql Load_File(TextFile) return BLOB string?

Tags: innodb, windows-7-x64, mysql-8.0

Windows 7, MySQL 8.0, InnoDB.
File contains ususal text, load result contains BLOB string.

select load_file('d:/temp.txt');

result: 0x62...43

Why it happens? And can i get TEXT result whithout convert()?

Comment: LOAD_FILE() **always** returns binary string. CAST() the output to CHAR. CONVERT() needed only when you need in charset convertion.

Comment: @Akina I see, ty.